# Migrating from android.util.log

Tags: java, android, logging

I'm taking class files in an Android library and moving the non-Android specific classes (data structures, etc.) in to a plain java library. Some of these classes are using android.util.Log for logging. I'd like to retain the logging, but not be dependent on the android logger in my plain java library. Ideally, the logging substitute would still go to the android logger when running in an android program.

What is the best course of action to take here? Can I just substitute in java.util.Logging?

Comment: You could create your own class that wraps Logging or use some library as Timber (https://github.com/JakeWharton/timber).

Answer (score 1):

I advise you to use SLF4J in your library and combine it with a Logback implementation for Android.

```
    [group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.7+']

    [group: 'com.github.tony19', name: 'logback-android-core', version: '1+'],
    [group: 'com.github.tony19', name: 'logback-android-classic', version: '1+']
```

SLF4J is a library that provides a logging interface without an implementation. Any logging implementation library (like Logback or Log4j) can be compiled into your app to provide the actual logging configuration and output.

Comment: So my plain java library would use the built in java logging utility, but my android library would use SLF4J? I have other android libraries that I probably won't touch that are using the Android logger. Would those have to be changed to do SLF4J?

Comment: Your library would use SLF4J for both Android and the desktop app. SLF4J automatically binds to a backend on the classpath. For Android, your app would add [`logback-android`](https://github.com/tony19/logback-android) to its classpath, while your desktop app would add [`logback`](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback).